# Create Yaml without file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

For some dark reasons, I have to convert a specific formated array to hash and a solution was to go through YAML.

I didn't reach to convert an array to hash through yaml without creating a file, could you help me ?

My Original Array could be like this one :

```
[
  ["lvl1"],
  [nil,"lvl2"],
  [nil, nil, "lvl3", "value1", "value2", "value3"],
  [nil, "lvl2bis"],
  [nil, nil, "lvl3bis", "value1bis", "value2bis", "value3bis"]
]
```

I transform this Array to string:

- For a string

  ```
  yml_text = []
  array.each do |line|
    yml_line = line.join(",").gsub(/\G,/, '  ').sub(/,+\z/, ']').sub(/:,+/, ':  [')
    yml_text << yml_line
  end
  yml_text = yml_text.join("\n")
  ```
- For a file

  ```
  f = File.open(yml_file_path, "w")
  array.each do |line|
    yml_line = line.join(",").gsub(/\G,/, '  ').sub(/,+\z/, ']').sub(/:,+/, ':  [')
    f.puts(yml_line)
  end
  f.close
  ```

I got the following result:

```
lvl1:
  lvl2:
    lvl3: ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
  lvl2bis:
    lvl3bis: ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
```

**If I save this text in a yml file** and parse it like this:

```
hash = YAML.load(File.read(yml_file_path))
```

I got my hash:

```
{ "lvl1" => {
    "lvl2" => {
      "lvl3" => ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
    },
    "lvl2bis" => {
      "lvl3bis" => ["value1bis", "value2bis", "value3bis"]
    }
  }
}
```

**If I do not save this text as yml file** and try to load my yml_text, I obtain this :

```
yml_data = YAML.load(yml_text)
p yml_data
"lvl1 lvl2 lvl3,value1,value2,value3 lvl2bis lvl3bis,value1bis,value2bis,value3bis"
```

**Is it impossible to go through YAML without creating a file ?**

Comment: I would guess you forgot to run `yml_text  = yml_text.join("\n")`, could you show us the value of yml_text before `YAML.load(yml_text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't answer your YAML question as such, just converts the array directly into a hash:

```
def to_hash(array)
  default = ->(hash, key) { hash[key] = Hash.new(&default) }
  keys = []
  array.inject(Hash.new(&default)) do |hash, element|
    compacted = element.compact
    if compacted.length > 1
      nested_hash = keys.inject(hash) { |sub_hash, key| sub_hash[key] }
      nested_hash[compacted.shift] = compacted
    else
      keys = keys.take(element.count(nil))
      keys[keys.length] = compacted.shift
    end
    hash
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank your for providing me a solution without YAML and which is faster than I expected.

Comment: NP. Was an interesting challenge, and I figured it'd be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
YAML.load(
  inp.map(&:dup).map do |a| # #dup is required for safe #shift below
    count, arr = (0...a.size).each do |i|
      curr = a.shift
      break [i, curr] unless curr.nil?
    end
    "  " * count << arr << ": " << (a.empty? ? "" : a.inspect)
  end.join($/)
)
#⇒ {"lvl1"=>{"lvl2"=>{"lvl3"=>["value1", "value2", "value3"]},
#     "lvl2bis"=>{"lvl3bis"=>["value1bis", "value2bis", "value3bis"]}}}
```